# How to prevent new instance of AVAudioPlayer Class being created every time View Controller is loaded - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I am building a simple Audio Player app using Swift. I have two View Controllers in my Storyboard. The second View Controller creates an instance of the AVAudioPlayer and is used to play audio. I want the user to be able to navigate away from that view controller, use other features in the app and go back to that view controller to manipulate the player.

The problem is that when I play some audio, navigate away and then go back to the players View Controller and press play again, two versions of the audio file are played at the same time.

I'm guessing that it is creating a new instance of the AVAudioPlayer object, rather than manipulating the one I made first. I think this has something to do with Swift de-allocating and then re-initializing the Player View Controller?

Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
  let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("daftPunk", ofType: "mp3")!
  @IBOutlet var volumePosition: UISlider!
  @IBOutlet var scrubPosition: UISlider!
  @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the fastest solution would be to create a singleton class that wraps the AVAudioPlayer object.

```
class AudioPlayer {
   var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
   let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("daftPunk", ofType:     "mp3")!
   static let sharedInstance = AudioPlayer()
   init() { }
}
```

and then use AudioPlayer.sharedInstance.player.play(). In this way, you will always only have one instance of AudioPlayer and thus AVAudioPlayer.